# how to trace for a javascript function which executes the drop down menu div/css values

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu, mouseover, trace

Is there a way to change the drop down menu's sub menu display location(x and y value)?

please check here for the template 
http://buyshop.ethemeuk.com/magento/themeview/?id=dark&redirect=0

please navigate to "WOMEN -> DRESSES -> **(sub-menu)**"
as you can see, the sub-menu overlays on menu which is above sub-menu.  This makes switching slightly inconvenient.

if there is a javascript function which is executing the mouseover ability, what is the best practice to trace the function which does the drop down menu?  I would like to place the drop down menu perhaps on a different (x:y) or just simply right below the menu to avoid overlaying.

I have basic understanding of firebug, I can see the divs/css values, but not sure where to begin when there is tons of javascript files on the template/theme.

How can we trace and find our way back to make the changes specifically for this menu.
Please point me to the right direction,  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chrome.

Right click on the submenu and choose "inspect element".

Then in the developer tools panel that opens, click on the "Event Listeners" header on the right-hand side.

Then expand "mouseover" and there will be direct links to the scripts and if you click on them, it will even take you to the exact line in the code :)